# Combining jquery each() and change()

Tags: jquery, events, each

I need to trigger the (almost) same callback on an element, both for initialization, and every time the value of the (input) element changes, like so:

```
$crud.find('input.filter,output.filter,select.filter,textarea.filter')
  .each(function() {
    let compare = _compare(this.value);
    if (compare[0] !== null) {
      $crud.data('filter',{...$crud.data('filter'),[this.name]: {operator:compare[0],value:compare[1]} });
      $(this).closest('.crud-filter').addClass('filtered');
    } else {
      $crud.data('filter',{...$crud.data('filter'),[this.name]: {operator:null,value:null} });
      $(this).closest('.crud-filter').removeClass('filtered');
    }
  })
  .change(function() {
    let compare = _compare(this.value);
    if (compare[0] !== null) {
      $crud.data('filter',{...$crud.data('filter'),[this.name]: {operator:compare[0],value:compare[1]} });
      $(this).closest('.crud-filter').addClass('filtered');
    } else {
      $crud.data('filter',{...$crud.data('filter'),[this.name]: {operator:null,value:null} });
      $(this).closest('.crud-filter').removeClass('filtered');
    }
    _display($crud,true);
  })
```

I know, I can compbine two events using the on() jquery method. But 'each' is not an event, and I'm not sure whether there is a "initialize once" event.... The pseudo code of what I would like to do is:

```
$crud.find('selector').on('each change', callback).change(_display($crud,true);
```

Run the `callback` once at document load, and every time the value changes, plus, when the value changes (but not on document load) run the `_display()` function.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: why not keep that `change` event separate and just use `$(this).trigger("change")` whenever you need to call the change event ?

Comment: If you move your code to a defined function (rather than inline anonymous) then you get:   `$crud.find('selector').each(your_func).change(() => { your_func(); _display($crud,true); });`